# How to show only numbers from null count (Python) using For Loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

'''
Hi all, I know that df.isnull().sum() tells you the column name and the sum of the null values under each column.

e.g.:

year                 0

month                0

state                0

number_of_fires    132

date                 0

What if you only want to show the numbers and not the name using For Loop?
0

0

0

132

0

Appreciate all help, thank you.
'''

Comment: `df.isnull().sum().values`?

Comment: `for k in df.isnull().sum(): print(k)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yu can use:

```
df.isna().sum().values
```

to get a list of the null counts without the column names.

To print the list values with for-loop, you can use:

```
for i in df.isna().sum().values:
    print(i)
```

or simply:

```
for i in df.isna().sum():
    print(i)
```

Comment: thank you! What if a For loop must be used?

Comment: df.isna().sum().to_list().  will return it as a list.

Comment: @Scoutboy84  What you want to do with the for loop ?   To iterate through the list to display list contents ?

Comment: its a project requirement.

Comment: @Scoutboy84  See edit above with for-loop.